# Closed form of $\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x \right) }{{x}^{3} \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}+1 \right) }}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Does it possibly have a closed form?

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x
 \right) }{{x}^{3} \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}+1 \right) }}{dx}$$

Thank you! I found it. No more need for efforts.

Comment: Care to share it with us?

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open, if only to allow the OP to provide their possible closed form.

Comment: I think people are understandably curious; I left WA cranking on it for five minutes without resolution.  (Namagiri, eh?  With Ramanujan unavailable, perhaps we might beseech you to show the result to us?)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is really what you'd call a "closed form" but this is the best I got:$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^3 (e^x + 1)} dx = \frac\pi4 - \frac{\log 2}3 -\frac 1 8-\frac 3 2 \zeta'(-1) -\frac 1 2\Im\log\Gamma(i) + \Im\log\Gamma(i/2) - \frac 1 2\Re\log G(1+i) + 2\Re\log G(1 + i/2) - 2\Re\zeta'(-1,i/2) + \frac 1 2 \Re\zeta'(-1,i) + 4\Im\zeta'(-2,i/2) - \frac 12\Im\zeta'(-2,i)\approx - 0.189
 $$
where $G$ is the [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function), $\zeta'(\cdot)$ is the derivative of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), $\zeta'(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the derivative of the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) in the first argument, and $\Re$ and $\Im$ are real and imaginary parts, respectively.

For this proof, all numbered equations will be proven at the bottom so that the flow of the proof is (slightly) more readable.

To prove this we use $$
 \int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^3} e^{-t x} dx = \frac12(t - (t^2 + 1)\mathrm{arccot}(t))\tag{1}
 $$
    thus we can expand the original integral as a geometric series $$
 \int_0^\infty \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^3 (e^x + 1)} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^3 (e^{-x} + 1)} e^{-x}dx =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^3} e^{-k x} dx= \frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k (k - (k^2 + 1)\mathrm{arccot}(k)). 
 $$
    This was observed in the comments on Claude Leibovici's answer. While the sum is certainly nasty, it is not impossible. Recalling that $\mathrm{arccot}(z) = \Im \log(i - z)$ for real $z$ (this follows from its [logarithmic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)). Thus the above sum may be written as $$
 \Im\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k (ki + \frac12 +(1+k^2)\log(k)- (k^2+ 1)\log(i+k)\right)
 $$
    Let $$F(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \left(kz - \frac12z^2 +(1+k^2)\log(k)- (k^2+ 1)\log(z+k)\right)
 $$
    Thus our goal is to compute $\frac12\Im F(i)$. To find $F$ is a somewhat closed form, we differentiate to obtain $$
 F'(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \left(k - z - \frac{k^2 + 1}{z+k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(z + k)(k - z) - k^2 - 1}{z+k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{-z^2 - 1}{z+k} = \frac{(z^2 + 1)}{2}\left(\psi(\frac{z+2}{2}) - \psi(\frac{z+1}{2})\right)
 $$
    where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Observing that $F(0) = 0$, we now simply have to compute $$
 F(z) = \int_0^z \frac{1+x^2}{2}\left(\psi(\frac{x+2}{2}) - \psi(\frac{x+1}{2})\right) dx
 $$
    Integration by parts yields \begin{eqnarray}
 F(z) &=& \int_0^z \frac{1+x^2}{2}\left(\psi(\frac{x+2}{2}) - \psi(\frac{x+1}{2})\right) dx = (1+z^2)\left(\log\Gamma(\frac{z+2}{2}) - \log\Gamma(\frac{z+1}{2})\right) + \log\Gamma(\frac12) \\&&- 2\int_0^z x \left(\log\Gamma(\frac{x+2}{2}) - \log\Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2})\right)dx \\
 &=& (1+z^2)\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{z+2}2)}{\Gamma(\frac{z+1}2)}\right) + \log\Gamma(\frac12) - 2 \int_0^z x\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{x+2}2)}{\Gamma(\frac{x+1}2)}\right)dx
 \end{eqnarray}
    So we have converted one difficult integral into another difficult integral. We will need to integrate $x\log\Gamma (x)$ (see bottom for proof):\begin{equation}
 \int_0^z x\log\Gamma(x)dx = \frac{z^2(3-4z)}{24} + \frac{z^2}{8}\log2\pi + \frac{z^2}2\log\Gamma(z) - \frac{z}{2}\log G(z+1) +\frac12\int_0^z\log G(x+1)dx \tag{2}
 \end{equation}
    For ease of reading's sake, we will call this integral $h(z)$. By Legendre's duplication formula, we have $$
 \frac{\Gamma(\frac{x}2 + 1)}{\Gamma(\frac{x}2 + \frac{1}{2})} = \frac{x\Gamma(x/2)^2}{2^{2-x}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(x)}
 $$
    which gives us \begin{eqnarray}
 &&\int_0^z x\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{x+2}2)}{\Gamma(\frac{x+1}2)}\right)dx = \int_0^z x\log\left(\frac{x\Gamma(x/2)^2}{2^{2-x}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(x)}\right)dx \\
 &=&\int_0^z x\log x dx + 2\int_0^zx\log\Gamma(x/2)dx - (\log 2)\int_0^z x(2-x)dx -\frac{\log\pi }{2}\int_0^z x dx - \int_0^z x\log\Gamma(x) dx\\
 &=& \frac{z^2(2\log z - 1)}4 + 8 h(z/2) - \frac{z^2 (3-z)\log 2}{3} - \frac{z^2\log\pi}{4} - h(z)
 \end{eqnarray}
    Hence we have $$
 F(z) = (1+z^2)\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{z+2}2)}{\Gamma(\frac{z+1}2)}\right) + \log\Gamma(\frac12) - \frac{z^2(2\log z - 1)}2 - 16h(z/2) + \frac{2z^2(3-z)\log 2}{3} +\frac{z^2\log\pi}{2} + 2h(z)
 $$
    Plugging in $z=i$ we have $$
 F(i) = \log(\Gamma(\frac12)) - \frac{1-2\log i}2 - 16h(i/2) - \frac{2(i-3)\log 2}3 - \frac{\log\pi}{2} + 2h(i)
 $$
    Taking the imaginary part, the real portions disappear and we find (recalling $\log i = \pi/2 i$): $$
 \Im F(i) = \frac\pi2 -16\Im h(i/2) - \frac{2\log 2}3 +2\Im h(i)
 $$
    Of course, now we have to deal with $h$. For real $t$ we have \begin{eqnarray}
 \Im h(i t) &=& \Im\left(\frac{t^2(4it - 3)}{24} - \frac{t^2}{8}\log{2\pi} - \frac{t^2}{2}\log\Gamma(i t) - \frac{i t}2\log{G(i t+1)} +\frac12\int_0^{it}\log G(x+1) dx\right)\\
 &=& \frac{t^3}{6} - \frac{t^2}2\Im\left(\log\Gamma(i t)\right) -\Im\left(\frac{i t}{2} \log G(i t + 1)\right) + \frac12\Im\int_0^{i t} \log G(x + 1) dx
 \end{eqnarray}
    The integral on the end is bad, but was considered by Adamchik (1998). Plugging $z= i t$ into his equation (19), we obtain $$
 \int_0^{i t} \log G(x+1) dx = \frac{ i t (1 + 2t^2)}{12} - \frac{t^2}{4}\log(2\pi) + i t\left(\zeta'(-1) + \zeta'(-1,i t)\right) + \zeta'(-2) - \zeta'(-2,i t) 
 $$
    whose imaginary part yields $$
 \Im\int_0^{i t} \log G(x+1) dx = \frac{t (1 + 2t^2)}{12}+ t \zeta'(-1)+t\Re(\zeta'(-1,i t)) - \Im(\zeta'(-2,i t)) 
 $$
    Plugging in $t = 1$ and $t=1/2$, we obtain the needed particular values:\begin{eqnarray}
 \Im\int_0^{i} \log G(x+1) dx &=& \frac{1}{4}+ \zeta'(-1)+ \Re \zeta'(-1,i) - \Im\zeta'(-2,i)\\
 \Im\int_0^{i /2} \log G(x+1) dx &=& \frac1{16}+ \frac12 \zeta'(-1) +\frac12\Re\zeta'(-1,i /2)- \Im\zeta'(-2,i /2)
 \end{eqnarray}
    This is all of the integration we must do, now all that remains is to plug back in. Firstly, \begin{eqnarray}
 \Im h(i) &=& \frac16 - \frac12\Im(\log\Gamma(i)) - \frac12\Re(\log G(i+1)) + \frac18 +\frac12\zeta'(-1) + \frac12 \Re\zeta'(-1,i) - \frac12\Im\zeta'(-2,i)\\
 \Im h(i/2) &=& \frac1{48} - \frac18\Im(\log\Gamma(i/2)) - \frac14\Re(\log G(1+i/2)) + \frac1{32} + \frac14\zeta'(-1) + \frac14\Re\zeta'(-1,i/2) - \frac12\Im\zeta'(-2,i/2)
 \end{eqnarray}
    And finally, \begin{eqnarray}
 \frac {1}{ 2}\Im F(i) &=& \frac {1}{ 2}{\big[}\frac\pi2 - \frac{2\log 2}3 - \frac{1}3 + 2\Im\left(\log\Gamma(i/2)\right) + 4\Re\left(\log G(1 + i/2)\right) -\frac 1 2 - 4\zeta'(-1) - 4\Re\zeta'(-1,i/2)\\&&  + 8\Im\zeta'(-2,i/2) + \frac 1 3 - \Im\log\Gamma(i) - \Re\log G(i+1) + \frac 1 4 + \zeta'(-1) + \Re\zeta'(-1,i) - \Im\zeta'(-2,i){\big]}\\
 &=& \frac\pi4 - \frac{\log 2}3 -\frac 1 8-\frac 3 2 \zeta'(-1) -\frac 1 2\Im\log\Gamma(i) + \Im\log\Gamma(i/2) - \frac 1 2\Re\log G(1+i) + 2\Re\log G(1 + i/2) \\&& - 2\Re\zeta'(-1,i/2) + \frac 1 2 \Re\zeta'(-1,i) + 4\Im\zeta'(-2,i/2) - \frac 12\Im\zeta'(-2,i)
 \end{eqnarray}

**Proof of (1):**
    We begin by computing $\int_0^\infty \sin x e^{-t x} dx = \frac1{t^2 + 1}$ and $\int_0^\infty \cos x e^{-t x} = \frac{t}{1+t^2}$, which may be evaluated as the real and imaginary parts of $$
 \int_0^\infty e^{(i-t) x} dx = \frac1{t - i} = \frac{t + i}{t^2 + 1}
 $$
    which gives us the antiderivative of the $\sin$ integral $$
 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x e^{-t x} = \mathrm{arccot}(t) 
 $$
    Since the second derivative of $\frac12\left(t-(t^2+1)\mathrm{arccot}(t)\right)$ is $\frac{t}{t^2+ 1} - \mathrm{arccot}(t)$, so it differs from the integral by some linear function. Since the limit of both as $t$ goes to infinity is 0, they must be equal.

**Proof of (2):**
    [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function#Relation_to_the_Loggamma_integral) gives a closed form integral of $\log\Gamma(x)$ in terms of the Barnes G-function:
    $$
 \int_0^z \log\Gamma(x)dx = \frac{z(1-z)}2 + \frac{z}2 \log2\pi + z\log\Gamma(z) - \log G(1+z)
 $$ Integration by parts yields:\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_0^z x\log\Gamma(x) dx &=& \frac{z^2(1-z)}{2} + \frac{z^2}{2}\log{2\pi} + z^2\log\Gamma(z) - z\log G(z+1)\\ &&-\int_0^z \frac{x(1-x)}2 + \frac{x}{2}\log2\pi + x\log\Gamma(x) - \log G(x+1)dx\\
 &=& \frac{z^2(1-z)}{2} + \frac{z^2}{2}\log{2\pi} + z^2\log\Gamma(z) - z\log G(z+1) - \frac{z^2(3-2z)}{12} - \frac{z^2}4\log2\pi\\&& - \int_0^z x\log\Gamma(x)dx + \int_0^z\log G(x+1) dx\\
 &=& \frac{z^2(3 - 4z)}{12} + \frac{z^2}{4}\log 2\pi + z^2\log\Gamma(z) - z\log G(z+1)\\&&- \int_0^z x\log\Gamma(x)dx + \int_0^z\log G(x+1) dx
 \end{eqnarray}
    Solving for $\int_0^zx\log\Gamma(x)dx$ we obtain the desired equation:$$
 \int_0^z x \log\Gamma(x) dx = \frac{z^2(3-4z)}{24} + \frac{z^2}{8}\log2\pi + \frac{z^2}2\log\Gamma(z) - \frac{z}{2}\log G(z+1) +\frac12\int_0^z\log G(x+1)dx
 $$

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a proof of anything.**

Using a CAS, I did not arrive anywhere ! So, I computed the integral numerically and arrived to $$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x
 \right) }{{x}^{3} \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}+1 \right) }}{dx} \simeq-0.188982$$ Searching this number in RIES, the best approximation is $$\frac{-1}{\left(e+\frac{1}{\pi }\right)^{3/2}} \simeq -0.1889819804605650703920758$$ I must confess that I am quite happy to find $e$,$\pi$ and $3$ here.

Comment: The Maple code $$ evalf(Int((x*cos(x)-sin(x))/(x^3*(exp(x)+1)), x = 0 .. infinity), 20) $$ produces $-.18898229620011986786, $ disabusing us. BTW, I wonder the upvoter.

Comment: @user64494.This is really bad news !

Comment: By writing $\frac{1}{e^x + 1} = \frac{e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-x}}$ and using the geometric series and Mathematica, I found that the integral equals $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} (-1)^k (k - (1+k^2) \mathrm{acot}\, k)$.

Comment: @ user111187 : Unfortunately, this is not a closed-form expression.

Comment: @user111187. It is nice even if not closed form; better than a series of digits ! Thanks.

Comment: The result I posted above is off by a minus sign. There may be a way to sum it using residues or something.

Comment: @ user 111187 & Claude Leibovici: The above series diverges.

Comment: @user64494 Are you sure? I numerically computed it with Mathematica and it gives the right answer (~ -0.18898).

Comment: @ user 111187 : You are right:the Maple code $$asympt(k-(k^2+1)*arccot(k), k, 4)$$ outputs $$-2/3\,{k}^{-1}+O \left( {k}^{-3} \right). $$